# Can I get the value of an environment variable in routes.php (or other config files)?

Tags: config, multi-environment, environmentvariables

I am trying to get the value of an environment variable (defined in the general.php config file) in the routes.php config file. Is it possible or not? I tried `$environmentVariables = craft()->config->get('environmentVariables')['myVariable']` but that throws an error: `Call to undefined function craft()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll just need to do something like this in your `routes.php` file:

```
$general = require __DIR__.'/general.php';

return array(
    'foo' => $general['environmentVariables']['bar'],
);
```